# Why doesn't the event listener not get called?

Tags: jquery, html

Following is a simple code, that displays a hyperlink and on clicking it, a alert box should be visible. But I do not see it. What could be the reason for it ? I suspect the script itself is not being called. Where am I going wrong ?

html :

```
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href='#' id='sign-up-link'>Sign up</a>
    <!-- scripts -->
    <script href='jquery-2.1.1.js'></script>
    <script href='script.js'></script>
</body>
```

script.js :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert('Into the ready function');
    $('#sign-up-link').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Hey !!');
        /*$('#sign-up-pop-up').style('display','block');
        $('#sign-up-pop-up').style('top','500px');
        $('$sign-up-pop-up').addClass('animated zoomIn');*/
    });
});
```

Comment: Is your "Into the ready function" alert displaying on page_load?

Comment: The code runs just fine, as you can see here on this jsfiddle version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/dp9qyfn4/, so it could be that there are errors elsewhere on your page.

Comment: Check your console log for javascript errors. If your jQuery script path is wrong, `$` will generate an error because $ is a jQuery alias.

Comment: @HaigBedrosian its all fine

Comment: Since the javascript it fine, it could be that the way you are loading your javascript into the page is throwing things off. You should have <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>. Also, check that you are not using IE 6/7/8, since jQuery 2.x doesn't support these browsers like 1.x does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
<script href='jquery-2.1.1.js' />
<script href='script.js' />
```

to:

```
<script src='jquery-2.1.1.js'></script>
<script src='script.js'></script>
```

You are putting `href` instead of `src` and also missing script closing tags `</script>`

Answer (score 4):

You should use `src` attribute instead of the `href` for the `script` elements.

Comment: I changed but the same result. I have also edited the question with `src`

Comment: Also, putting your external script references in the head section makes your code more organized.

Comment: @saplingPro fixing errors in question (changing `href` to `src`) makes answers to look strange... Don't do such things in future.

Comment: FWIW Stan, it is better practice in terms of performance to put `<script>` elements at the end of the document, just before the end body tag. This then allows the browser to load markup before loading javascript, thus speeding up the rendering of page content (improves the user experience) and deferring the loading of script libraries to the very end.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script src="//yourJavaSCriptFile.js"></script>
```

You have to have both:

```
 <script>
 </script>
```